# Rails left join can't get unexpected result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, left-join

I have 3 table products, carts and users, and I wanna left join from carts to 
products

Here's the column of two tables

Product:

- id
- name
- description
- price

Cart:

- id
- product_id
- user_id

Users:

- id
- others column...

Relations are:
Cart to Product(1 to many), Cart to User(1 to many)

Here's the code I wrote to left join from carts to products

```
@carts = Cart.left_outer_joins(:product).select('products.name')
```

But I get nil value of column name...

[image]

Comment: You didn't put it in `select`, what did you expect? What informations are you trying to retreive with this query?

Comment: cart.* and product.name

Comment: I've done it before, but still get nil of name column

Comment: Can you add your models? How can your cart have many products and have a product_id column?

Answer (score 0):

You don't "get" name because `joins` with "custom" `select` doesn't change the way `ActiveRecord` object is displayed in your console. But if you do this:

```
carts = Cart.left_outer_joins(:product).select('carts.*, products.name as product_name')
cart = carts.first
cart.product_name
```

you'll get your product name.